# VBA - Trying to get the root of a function

Tags: excel, vba, equation-solving

I got this equation to solve in VBA:

```
Energy = y + (0.5) ^ 2 / ( 2 * 9.81 * y ^ 2 )
```

but I got the `Energy` value and want to solve for the `y` value.

In R is easy: [`uniroot`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/uniroot). There is something like this?

Comment: nop :/ maybe a i need an numerical method

Comment: There isn't anything in VBA for solving equations. There is Solver in Excel though, you can set up a model for that equation. Or you can try to [express `y` in terms of `Energy`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x+%3D+y+%2B+%280.5%29+%5E+2+%2F+%28+2+*+9.81+*+y+%5E+2+%29%2C+solve+for+y)...

Comment: What kind of energy do you calculate using that formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation is a cubic polynomial with two positive roots and one negative. We can eliminate the negative one, and consider a direct evaluation of the two positive roots with the following VBA code in a **Module**.

```
Global Const g As Double = 9.81
Global Const PI As Double = 3.14159265358979

Public Function CalcE(ByVal y As Double) As Double
    CalcE = y + (0.5) ^ 2 / (2# * g * y ^ 2)
End Function

Public Function SolveForY(ByVal E As Double, Optional ByVal second As Boolean = False) As Double
    ' Solve "E = y + (0.5) ^ 2 / ( 2 * g * y ^ 2 )" for "y"
    If Not second Then
        SolveForY = E / 3# - 2# * E * Sin(Asin((16# * E ^ 3# * g - 27#) / (16# * E ^ 3# * g)) / 3#) / 3#
    Else
        SolveForY = E / 3# + 2# * E * Sin(Asin((16# * E ^ 3 * g - 27#) / (16# * E ^ 3 * g)) / 3# + PI / 3#) / 3#
    End If
End Function
```

and the supporting `Asin()` function defined in terms of `Atn()`.

```
Public Function Asin(ByVal x) As Double
    If Abs(x) < 1# Then
        Asin = Atn(x / Sqr(1# - x * x))
    Else
        Asin = 2 * Atn(1) * Sgn(x)
    End If
End Function
```

Some example results are

> ```
> ? SolveForY(1#)
> 0.12035578724076 
>
> ? SolveForY(1#, True)
> 0.986917853921696
> ```

And checking the solutions

> ```
> ? CalcE(0.12035578724076)
>  0.999999999999997 
>
> ? CalcE(0.986917853921696)
>  1
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using **algebra**:

```
Energy = y  +  (0.5)^2  /  ( 2 * 9.81 * y^2 )
Energy = y  + .25  /  ( 19.62 * y^2 )
Energy  *  ( 19.62  *  y^2 ) = y  *  ( 19.62  *  y^2 )  +  .25
Energy  *  19.62  *  y^2  = 19.62  *  y^3  +  .25
0  = 19.62 *  y^3   -  Energy * 19.62  *  y^2  +  .25
```

and apply standard techniques:

[Previous Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13457212/cubic-roots-using-vba)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a translation of John Alexiou's answer from VBA to Excel formulas. If energy in in cell `B2` then the three solutions are given by:

```
=B2/3-2*B2*SIN((ASIN((16*B2^3*9.81-27)/(16*B2^3*9.81))+0*PI())/3)/3
=B2/3-2*B2*SIN((ASIN((16*B2^3*9.81-27)/(16*B2^3*9.81))+4*PI())/3)/3
=B2/3-2*B2*SIN((ASIN((16*B2^3*9.81-27)/(16*B2^3*9.81))+2*PI())/3)/3
```

The third equation gives negative `y`.